# Оператор case не работает с большими числами?

Tags: delphi

Я определяю типы графических файлов по их заголовкам, например:

```
var stream : TFileStream;
buff   : int64;
…
stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyRead);
  stream.Read(buff, sizeof(buff));
  stream.Free;
  case (buff and $FFFFFFFF) of
    $E0FFD8FF : result := 'JPEG IMAGE';
    $E2FFD8FF : result := 'JPEG CANNON EOS JPEG FILE';
…
```

Используя http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=all&order=EXT&alpha=P.
Но когда я подставляю сигнатуру для *«*.*png»* - `$0A1A0A0D474E5089` (в **8 байт**) в `case`:

```
case buff of
    $0A1A0A0D474E5089 : result := 'PNG';
end
```

у меня ошибка:

> Constant expression violates subrange bounds

Как быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как сказано в документации, ограничение 32 бита: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Case_Statements

> any expression of an ordinal type smaller than 32 bits (string types and ordinals larger than 32 bits are invalid)

Выход - делать приведение к 32 битам или писать в блоке `else`

```
case (buff and $FFFFFFFF) of
  $E0FFD8FF: Result := 'JPEG IMAGE';
  $E2FFD8FF: Result := 'JPEG CANNON EOS JPEG FILE';
  $474E5089: if buff shr 32 = $0A1A0A0D then Result := 'PNG'; // <-- вариант номер 1
else
  if buff = $0A1A0A0D474E5089 then // <-- вариант номер 2
    Result := 'PNG';
end;
```